# Android Studio - Can't connect to device (Samsung Galaxy S7)

Tags: android, android-studio, galaxy

I've got an issue while trying to run an app on android studio. The list of connected device will always remain empty. Thus I can't deploy my app on the phone. The OS is Windows 10.

I already take these steps:

- installed driver from Samsung. The device is shown in device manager and I've got access from windows to it
- Swapping USB Ports a dozen times
- Developer Setting on
- Switched Media Port both Camera (Ptp) and Media Device (MTP)

Does anyone has further tips?

Comment: Have you enable "USB debugging" in Developer options from Settings?

Comment: You Have to enable "Debug USB" in developer options on your S7.

Comment: which os u have use?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Look if **USB debugging** is enable in the developer options of your smartphone.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, it worked! This was the forgotten setting.